# Running multiple queries in Bigquery in one query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have question about is that possible to run in one query more than one queries that create tables?
Now i'm executing queries one by one using

```
Create or REPLACE TABLE x AS SELECT ...;
 
Create or REPLACE TABLE y AS SELECT ...;
```

What i need to have is to run specific query that create table X  and after job was done create table Y

Comment: You can run both DDL statements in a single script and BQ will execute each statement in a script sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create more than one table in one SQL query using the CREATE TABLE statement separated by semi-colon. You can achieve what you want by executing the above same script not one by one but by just running them as a whole.